# Timeout error after https configuration on CentOS 7

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, certificates, https, apache-virtualhost

I have an app that has been running for 2 years now via http. Now we want to move to https for better security. Our OS is CentOS Linux 7. We have a virtual host config in `/etc/httpd/sites-available` with the content below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.trade.xxx.com
    ServerAlias trade.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /ims/www/trade.xxx.com/public_html/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/divo/ssl_cert/wildcard_eneo_cm.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/divo/ssl_cert/wildcard_eneo_cm.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/divo/ssl_cert/DigiCertCA.crt
    ErrorLog /ims/www/trade.xxx.com/error.log
    CustomLog /ims/www/trade.xxx.com/requests.log combined
    <Directory "/ims/www/trade.xxx.com/public_html/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How ever when I visit `https://trade.xxx.com`, the browser just keeps loading and after some duration give ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

What can be the issue?

Researching, I did the following:

**Command 1**

```
openssl x509 -in wildcard_xxx_com.crt -noout -subject
```

**Output**

```
subject= /CN=*.xxx.com
```

**Command 2**

Checking whether httpd is listening to port 443 and below is the result

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      881/dnsmasq         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      880/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1013/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      905/mysqld          
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      10409/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      881/dnsmasq         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      880/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1013/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      10409/httpd
```

**Command 3**

Check if fire wall is enabled

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

From the result below, firewall is not enable so is not a firewall issue

```
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

**Command 4**

Check if ssl is enabled in ssl.conf and below can clearly show is on

```
#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
```

From the above, everything seems okay but I don't understand why doesn't work.
Where am I having blind spot. What config is missing?

Comment: The firewall is running but is it blocking traffic on the port. Run iptables -L

Comment: Anything interesting in the server's error logs? SELinux disabled or permissive, I guess?

Comment: `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: Hi @Raman Sailopal, the above is my result for iptables -L

Comment: Hi, @Ulrich Schwarz is enabled and is in Permissive mode.

Comment: Do you have a `port 443` or `Listen 443` or similar somewhere in your apache config, so that it actually does listen to that port? try `netstat -tnlp | grep :443` to see if a process is listening on that port.